# React Native render not being triggered after Redux action is dispatched

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm having this issue, the action is being dispatched, the reducer is being executed but the render function is not being triggered.

Container:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { renderVoterSearch } from '../actions';
import Search from '../components/Search';

class SearchContainer extends Component {
    render() {
       return (
           <Search {...this.props}/>
       );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        searchType: state.searchType,
        instruction: state.instruction,
        title: state.title
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        renderVoterSearch
    }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchContainer);
```

The action dispatched from the Search Component

```
export const renderVoterSearch = (tab) => ({
    type: RENDER_VOTER_SEARCH,
    searchType: tab.type,
    instruction: tab.instruction,
    title: tab.title
});
```

Reducer:

```
const search = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case RENDER_VOTER_SEARCH:
            return {
                ...state,
                searchType: action.searchType,
                instruction: action.instruction,
                title: action.title
            }   
        default:
           return state
    }
}
```

Here's the complete code 
https://github.com/mivotico/mivotico-react-native/tree/redux-first-steps/app

I've been reading that one of the reasons may be that the state is being mutated but already checked and didn't see any mutation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue! Was that I didn't know the reducers were inside the state, so if the reducer is called "search" then in the `mapStateToProps` function to access this state should be `state.search` instead of just `state`.